# Site has fake users registered with a similar pattern in username and email

Tags: errors, security, user-registration, spam, bug

Website keeps getting hundred of fake users.

Registration form has **reCaptcha** but no effect.

By changing required fields in form to add First Name and Last Name **required** still fake users keep getting registered without adding First Name and Last Name.

The site has **admin approval** enabled. So fake users can't login and appear in the site.

The only way to stop the fake users that has been effective is to stop registering new users on the site. But that is not an option.

The fake accounts have a similar **pattern**.

```
username : angsobien1988
email : angsobien@gmail.com
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does your site really need blanket user registration?

Comment: What is blanket user registration? The site does require user registration.

Comment: Does everyone who accesses the site really need to have an account? Or is it just the people who add/manage content?

Comment: No. Not everyone has to have a user account. Just the people who offer their services can register to have their services offered with a profile so that anyone can see.

Comment: The only thin I can think of then is to try what I call a "reverse torture test", try a different Captcha, or check into a commercial solution.